# Node.js Express - run project as public

Tags: node.js, windows, express

In most time I run project on Linux as public and don't have troubles with it. But now I try run project on Windows also as [public](https://www.dropbox.com/s/du8xy72qsoynp9d/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-03-09%2020.41.09.png?dl=0). I [created](https://coderwall.com/p/mbov6w/running-nodejs-and-express-on-windows) rules for Windows Firewall. And when I try open page *192.168.0.106:3000* I get error, that server not working. How configure public Node.js Express project as public?

Thanks.

```js
this.app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '192.168.0.106', function () {
    console.log(chalk.green('Server started with port 3000'));
    var os = require('os');
    var interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    var addresses = [];
    for (var k in interfaces) {
        for (var k2 in interfaces[k]) {
            var address = interfaces[k][k2];
            if (address.family === 'IPv4' && !address.internal) {
                addresses.push(address.address);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(addresses);
});
```

Comment: Can you show a code snippet of how you are starting the server? Most likely you need to listen as `0.0.0.0` or "any" device but we'll see with a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is the listening route you want to listen on. The easiest solution is to set it to be [`0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) in order to listen on all routes.

```
this.app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0', function () {
    //...
})
```

Here is the documentation on the [http.listen](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) api. But when you specify a specific IP address that means that you will only be listening on that one route. When you try to call back to yourself as `192.168.0.x` then you're calling it from another route. Similarly so with `127.0.0.1`. Use `0.0.0.0` to listen on all routes.

Comment: I do like you say but I still can't get access to server page

Comment: locally all work good, I want get access from different device and places, use like simple site